# Stop Steam Sync Permanently

Tags: steam

While playing games via Steam, at the exit of the game Steam wants to "Sync" something. I guess it is game saves.

I am in a low bandwidth environment where it takes for ever for Steam client to finish sync'ing.

Is there a way to turn off sync to Steam-Cloud apart from offline mode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right click on the game in question, select "Properties". Go to the "Updates" tab, and uncheck the "Enable Steam Cloud synchronisation for {game name here}" checkbox.

[image: For single game]

Alternatively, to do it for all games, go to Syeam Preferences page, select the "Cloud" section, and uncheck "Enable Steam cloud synchronisation for applications which support it".

[image: Interface for all games]