# How Can I Delete My Player Data?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I made a character a few days ago on dungeon defenders and earned a lot of mana with him.  I then decided to start fresh and make a new character.  Then when I went to the tavern with that character I still had my mana (all 26 million of it :P)!  I searched for a way to delete my player data but could not find one.  How can I delete it?

Comment: What platform is this on?

Comment: I am playing on PC

Comment: Are you playing locally or online ("ranked ")

Comment: Only locally and non-ranked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Player save data is stored in the following location:

```
C:\Program Files\Trendy Entertainment\Dungeon Defenders\Binaries\Win32\DunDefHeroes.dun
```

There is also a backup located in the same place, but with `.bak` extension.

```
C:\Program Files\Trendy Entertainment\Dungeon Defenders\Binaries\Win32\DunDefHeroes.bak
```

Note that depending on your version of Windows, it may be under `Program Files (x86)` instead of `Program Files`.

Also, if you are playing through Steam, the files may be re-downloaded from the Cloud.  You can prevent this by [turning off Steam Cloud](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/150381/42984).

Comment: When playing using Steam, I found the Heroes files in `<steam install dir>/SteamApps/common/Dungeon Defenders/Binaries/Win32`

Comment: Also, you have to delete the DunDefHeroes.dun in `Program Files/Steam/<user id>/65800/remote` as well, otherwise stored data returns.